# swf file works in main folder but not in sub folder

Tags: flash

I've been rattling my brains out over this for the last few days and I'm getting nowhere.
I've checked through all the possible answers and still do not have a solution.

Here's my problem:

my site is laid out like this: 
in 'root' I have 'index.htm' and other folders below root one of which is 'pages' which has eyes.htm.

My 'swf' files are in the folder 'media' which is also in root.

- root  (folder) --> index.htm
- pages (folder) --> eyes.htm
- media (folder) --> shb_ticker.swf
- script (folder)
- css (folder)

In index.htm, I have a flash object in a div as below.

---

```
 <param name="movie" value="media/shb_ticker.swf" />
 <param name="quality" value="high" />
 <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
 <param name="swfversion" value="7.0.70.0" />
 <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
 <param name="expressinstall" value="scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
 <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
 <!--[if !IE]>-->
 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/shb_ticker.swf" width="970" height="28">
   <!--<![endif]-->
   <param name="quality" value="high" />
   <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
   <param name="swfversion" value="7.0.70.0" />
   <param name="expressinstall" value="scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
   <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
   <div>
     <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
     <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
   </div>
   <!--[if !IE]>-->
 </object>
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

This works fine in index.htm.

When I copy and amend the code in the sub folder 'pages' in eyes.htm (snippet below) I get nothing !!!

---

```
 <param name="movie" value="**../media/shb_ticker.swf**" />
 <param name="quality" value="high" />
 <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
 <param name="swfversion" value="7.0.70.0" />
 <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
 <param name="expressinstall" value="../scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
 <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
 <!--[if !IE]>-->
 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="**../media/shb_ticker.swf**" width="970" height="28">
   <!--<![endif]-->
   <param name="quality" value="high" />
   <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
   <param name="swfversion" value="7.0.70.0" />
   <param name="expressinstall" value="../scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
   <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
   <div>
     <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
     <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
   </div>
   <!--[if !IE]>-->
 </object>
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

I have looked through the internet and there is talk of relative paths, absolute paths, and flash using the path of the html file and not the swf etc all of which I did not understand.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.
Regards

Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - it was the software I was using to create the swf file that was the issue.
I've sorted it and it works fine now.

Apologies.

Sanjay

Comment: You might mention what software you were using and how you solved the issue. That way anyone else who runs into this will 1) be able to find this question in a google search, and 2) know how to solve it :)